# PHP - Can't display images from parent directories

Tags: php, image, path, relative-path

I am working on a program that involves displaying images stored in a server.
My working directory is

**~/public_html/lab5/**

The images are uploaded successfully to the following directory:

**~/public_html/lab5/uploads/**

Images ARE NOT displayed when I try to display the images using the path

**~/public_html/lab5/uploads/image.jpg**

but they are displayed normally using the following path

**uploads/image.jpg**

I'm just wondering, what is wrong with the relative-to-home path that I'm using?

Thanks in advance,

Rafi

Comment: You haven't shown how you're trying to show the images so it's impossible to say

Comment: @SamiKuhmonen My apologies. The code looks like the following:
**echo '<img src="~/public_html/lab5/uploads/image.jpg" alt="Image"/>';**

Answer (score 0):

It would be hard to say for sure without any idea what your server looks like, but I'm guessing based on the paths you've listed that ~/public_html/lab5 is your document root, in which case, the webserver doesn't know about anything except the contents of lab5 and its sub-directories.

Comment: The document root for the server is **~/** with **public_html** and **lab5** being sub-directories. I have had other programs accessing files from **~/SomeFolder/** and it worked perfectly